# Trying to only download files which got uploaded today

Tags: scripting, winscp

So everyday I download multiple .zip files from an SFTP server. Also everyday our client uploads new .zip files to this SFTP server, but is not willing to delete the old files.

So I download the same files of the last few days + the files which got uploaded today. 
I tried a lot but didn't have any success.

This is my short script right now (which downloads way to many files and eats my storage space up):

```
open sftp://user:password@sftp-server.com/ -hostkey=*
synchronize local D:/Test\Download /sftp-server/PDF-files/
```

I couldn't find an option to download files per date, so maybe you can help me further. 
Also important, the .zip files are named:

```
"name_clientname_YYYYMMDD_NumberOfUploads.zip"
```

I tried to add

```
*%TIMESTAMP#yyyymmdd%*.zip
```

at the end of the path of the files, but that didn't work out.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use synchronise if you are deleting the old files from your local copy. Select files based on timestamp instead:

From the winscp site: [How do I transfer new/modified files only?](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/faq_script_modified_files)

The appropriate [get](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/scriptcommand_get) syntax (close to what you tried) seems to be something like:

```
open sftp://user:password@sftp-server.com/ -hostkey=*
get -filemask="*.zip>today" /remote-folder/* D:\local-folder\
```

where the filemask constraint is as specified in: https://winscp.net/eng/docs/file_mask#size_time